# Using C# Dynamic to simply data access

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dynamic

I need to cache some look up tables in memory from sql database. I have hundreds of them. The tables are pretty simple with the following structure.

```
Tablename= "l_lookupobjectname"

column1Name: ID
Column2Name: Code
```

Code is mostly a string but can also be an integer in a few cases.

I use entity framework and would like a generic way to load those tables into my web application memory. I do not want to individually load each table by specifying its name.

I'm thinking along having a list of `dictionary<in id, dynamic code>`.

My problem is:

How do I generate the data access code that will pull all the data to my List of dictionary without having to write repetitive code for all my hundreds of table.
"select ID, Code from all the tables" instead calling this statement for each table.

I'm not concerned about the code for caching the data. This is quite trivial.

Comment: This seems very broad. Can you narrow down one single problem and ask a question about it? We aren't going to do your job... Mabye you're just explaining your problem poorly? Do you wan't generics - and not dynamics? Read [mcve]

Comment: Just added some clarification. Looking for a generic way to select from all the tables

Comment: Do you have a list of all your tables? String, Object, etc?

Comment: First, you need a way to get list of table names somehow. Since there are hundreds of them, you may want some formal rule, and I doubt, that you are going to make hundreds of properties in your db context.

Comment: i know they all start with "L_". This is part of the problem. I was thinking there is a way to tell sql to querry all tables starting with "l_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue might be types, unless you declare everything is a string or an object (and cast it as needed).

Other than that going with some nested dictionaries seems like your best bet. You can build SQL queries (`"select * from {0}"`), and just provide a list of tables. Then read each one into a dictionary.

You could use `DataSet`, but that is quite cumbersome. Probably `SqlDataReader` is better bet.

You can get column names from it by:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var columns = new List<string>();

for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
{
   columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
}
```

and then just read it all as strings or objects.